# Two containers on two hosts in same network: One can access other hosts on network, the other can't, why?

Tags: networking, iptables, masquerade

I have been running into a network issue recently with two containers (on two different hosts) in our network:

The container on the one host can ping/access physical hosts on a specific network while the other container on the second host can't, even though (as far as I can see) the configs are the same.

The details of the network are these:

1. there are two physical hosts (host01 and host02)
2. each one has a container running on it via LXC (container01 on host01 and container02 on host02)
3. both containers are connected to their respective host on a virtual LXC LAN in the range 10.0.10.0/24 with the hosts having IP 10.0.10.1 and the containers having IP 10.0.10.2
4. both physical hosts each have 4 physical network connections (across 2 NICs)
5. the two connections on NIC1 go into the switch for the *internal* network and are bonded together in a bond-interface called "internal"; the *internal* network has the IP range 10.0.80.0/24 and host01 has IP 10.0.80.100 while host02 has IP 10.0.80.200 here
6. the two connections on NIC2 go into the switch for the *DMZ* network and are bonded together in a bond-interface called "external"; the *DMZ* network has the IP range 10.0.90.0/24 and host01 has IP 10.0.90.100 while host02 has IP 10.0.90.200 here
7. both physical hosts have IPTABLES running and both have in the POSTROUTING chain two rules that masquerade all traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 to 0.0.0.0/0: one on "internal" and one on "external" bond-interface

(8. on the DMZ network there are several servers (mail, LDAP, etc) on other IPs in the 10.0.90.0/24 range)

(9. on the internal network there is a DNS server at 10.0.80.250 that also knows the hosts in the DMZ)

Now, the way I understand it, these MASQUERADE rules will ensure that all traffic generated by the containers that is sent out either into the internal network or the external network will not show the container's IP (10.0.10.2) but rather the *host's* IP for that respective network and translate back accordingly for any traffic coming into the container, right?

So if container01 sends traffic into the internal network, say to a host at 10.0.80.17, this host will see the internal IP of host01 (10.0.80.100) as the address the traffic came from and to which it sends responses, right? Same for traffic to the DMZ network, just replacing ".80." with ".90." here.

Now, for some reason both containers can ping/access ANY host on the internal network but only container01 can ping/access ANY host on the DMZ network, while container02 can't. Both host01 and host02 can ping/access ANY host in both networks, but for some reason container02 cannot access the DMZ...

When I send a ping from container02 to any host in the DMZ it says "unreachable". When I send a ping from container01 or any of the two physical hosts it works fine.

When I try to access a mailserver (IP: 10.0.90.2, hostname: mail.domain.com) in the DMZ, it works in container01 but not in container02. Running Wireshark in the containers while accessing the mailserver (via mail.domain.com) shows that container01 contacts the DNS server in the internal network, gets a response and then loads the according webinterface of the mailserver (@10.0.90.2/mail.domain.com). Wireshark on container02 shows that it also contacts the DNS server, gets a response (i.e. "mail.domain.com has IP 10.0.90.2") and then, as the immediate next packet, sends and ARP request reading "Who has 10.0.90.2? Tell 10.0.10.2", i.e. the *container's* virtual IP! Shouldn't this read "Tell 10.0.90.200", i.e. the DMZ-IP of host02?? Why is this not masquerading? Wireshark on container01 never shows it sending any ARP requests, just going straight to the mailserver's web interface right after the DNS response.

Running `dig` or `nslookup` on container02 with the hostname of the mailserver returns the right IP so DNS is working and contacting the internal DNS also works, it just can't access the DMZ, even though it should?

I even went and checked if the cables to the DMZ router are still connected and blinking but both is the case (which makes sense since host02 still can access the DMZ perfectly)... why would container02 be excluded? To me, it sounds like a problem with the masquerading and container02 not being shown with host02's IP to the DMZ??

Any suggestions will be helpful! Thanks in advance!